# Powershell: how get exception line number when using ScriptBlock::Invoke

Tags: powershell-4.0

How can I get the line number where the exception is thrown in this example? The example below only gives me the line number where I invoke the script block (i.e. $sb.Invoke()). I want the line number where I throw "Error in FooBar".

```
function Foobar {
    throw "Error in FooBar"
}

function Bar {
    FooBar
}

function Foo {
    Bar
}

try {
        $sb = ${function:Foo}
        $sb.Invoke()
    }
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    $script_name = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName
    write-host "<--Error: Occurred on line $line in script $script_name." 
    Write-host "<--Error: $ErrorMessage"
}
```

UPDATE:

If I change:

```
$sb = ${function:Foo}
$sb.Invoke()
```

to this:

```
$func_info = get-command Foo
Invoke-Command $func_info.ScriptBlock
```

it works.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a limitation of Invoke()'s error handling - it's passing on the error message but throwing away the invocation info.

One workaround is to catch and rethrow inside the scriptblock itself, but with more information, e.g.

```
$sb = {
    try {
        Foo
    }
    catch {
        throw "Error: $($_.Exception.Message). Stack trace:`n$($_.ScriptStackTrace)" 
    }
}
$sb.Invoke()
```

This outputs:

```
<--Error: Occurred on line 22 in script .
<--Error: Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "Error: Error in FooBar. Stack trace:
at Foobar, <No file>: line 2
at Bar, <No file>: line 6
at Foo, <No file>: line 10
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 16
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22"
```